# table column not contentEditable in ie10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, html-table, contenteditable

here is my pen: http://cdpn.io/GxIAd

When trying to get a table column to be contentEditable in ie10 I cannot seem to click and add text to the table column, any ninja tricks to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Though the TABLE, COL, COLGROUP, TBODY, TD, TFOOT, TH, THEAD, and TR
>   elements cannot be set as content editable directly, a content
>   editable SPAN, or DIV element can be placed inside the individual
>   table cells (TD and TH elements).

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537837(v=vs.85).aspx

So i suggesst you place a div or span around the content and set the attribute to this.